# What options are available for authenticating an AWS user via the JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

Our team needs to build an application to automate some set of tasks in AWS.

What options do we have for performing AWS automation on behalf of a user who has authorization to do some task, but doesn't necessarily authenticate through our utility? What I mean is, we'd like to perform some set of tasks for a user, but only after we've somehow validated their credentials against AWS - we don't want to store their credentials, only validate their authentication somehow.

Specifically, is there a part of their JS-SDK that would let us initiate an authentication flow?

Answer (score 2):

Users should not give you credentials. Users should define an IAM role in their account that specifies the minimum set of permissions that your service needs (you can help them by documenting the IAM policy). Then those users should [delegate](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#delegate-using-roles) access, allowing your account to assume that IAM role. To test validity, [assume the role](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html).